# Jquery select option value checkbox

Tags: jquery, select, checkbox

I have run into a bit of a problem which I hope someone can help me solve.

I have a searchform with some dropdown menus (A, B and C)

When I select option value B I need a checkbox to be unchecked

I have tried every solution I have found online, but I can't get it to work - I have tried to make a simple if statement but still no go.

Hope someone here can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please share what you have?

Comment: You can share your latest code so we can check for solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JQuery to uncheck the checkbox when your dropdown is selected than you check that selected values is b. if it is b than trough jquery unchecked checkbox

> Html

```
    <select name="dropdown" >
        <option value="A">option A</option>
        <option value="B">option B</option>
    <option value="C">option C</option>

         </select>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="" checked>
```

> jquery

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
             $('select[name="dropdown"]').change(function(){

                if ($(this).val() == "B")

                   $("#checkbox").removeAttr("checked");

            });​


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to uncheck the checkbox like so:

```
$("#checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
```

Have a look at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n6xot6ar/)